# Copy between database using pg_dump and SSH

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, pg-dump, ssh

I want to copy a tabel from one server to another using pg_dump and SSH.

Here is the script that I run from the source database :

```
pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -Fc --dbname=postgresql://postgres:passwd@127.0.0.1:5432/db_reference --table db_reference.education | ssh -C username@10.100.8.43 "psql -h 10.100.8.43 -U postgres -p 5432 x_db_test"
```

There is error: `host key verification failed`

Questions :

1. Is the command correct?
2. How to remove the error?

Thanks

Comment: Do some basic debugging.  Make sure you can ssh into the intended machine as a standalone command, before trying to hook it into your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `pg_dump` via the `ssh` command so you have a one-liner:

```
filename="tmp/backup_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).sql"

ssh user@IP \
  "pg_dump --no-owner postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname" \
  >"$filename"
```